# Get existing form with earlier values in sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting questions from questions table in db.
I'm saving question_id and answer_value with an unique form_id and user_id to answers table in database.

I would like for the user to be able to update the form another day. So how can i get and display the form with answer_value already filled out based on the users earlier answer?

This is how i display questions from db:

```
<form action="/form/insert.php" method="POST">
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions where active=1 AND question_sort=1 ORDER BY sort_by";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
      echo '<tr>
       <td class="question">'.$body.'</td>
       <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="0" ></td>
       <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="1" ></td>
       <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="2" ></td>
          </tr>';
}
</form>
```

This is how i save every unicqe form to db:

```
 $question_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_id']);
 $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
 $form_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['form_id']);
 $form_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 foreach ($_POST['answer_value'] as $question_id => $answer_id){

$sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_value, user_id, form_id,   form_date)
VALUES ({$question_id}, {$answer_id}, $user_id, {$form_id}, '$form_date')";
```

Comment: It seems to be bit puzzled. Each form post stores a new set of answers to the DB. You're retrieving all of them, but there must either be duplicates or you are getting errors on the insert (`DUPLICAT KEY ...`) and not storing anything.

Comment: @Axel Amthor thx for your time, the code I posted is just for getting the questions from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop through the values and match to the answer value you stored

```
<form action="/form/insert.php" method="POST">
<?php
$vals=array(0,1,2);
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions where active=1 AND question_sort=1 ORDER BY sort_by";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$body = $row['question_body'];
$question_id = $row['question_id'];
  echo '<tr>
   <td class="question">'.$body.'</td>';
   foreach($vals as $x){
    $s='';
    if($x==$row['answer_value']){
        $s="selected";
    }
    echo '<td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']"     value="'.$x.'" '.$s.'></td>';
   }
echo '</tr>';
}
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: thx for your help. It solved it, i just had to change selected to checked on $s variable. Thx again! :)